# DEs with fixed solution involving difference of ratios with tiny denominators

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm trying to numerically solve coupled DEs of the form:

```
a'(t) = b(t) / b0(t) - a(t) / a0(t)
b'(t) = a(t) / a0(t) - b(t) / b0(t)
```

where the functions `a0(t)` and `b0(t)` take a form similar to:

```
a0(t) = 1 / (1 + exp(20 * (t - 0.6))
b0(t) = 1 / (1 + exp(20 * (t - 0.3))
```

For large values of `t`, both `a0(t)` and `b0(t)` become very small which causes issues with calculating `a'(t)` and `b'(t)`; however, the behaviour is mathematically perfectly fine.  For example, solving the above equation results in:

[image: DE solution]

Where it is evident that the system reaches a fixed solution.

What can be done in order to increase the numerical stability of this differential equation?  Or are there certain methods which might work better than Runge-Kutta to solve this?

Comment: My first reflex was to re-express this as DEs with respect to `(a_0(t)*a(t))`, but this leads to equations of the form `(a0*a)' = a0/b0^2 (b0*b) + (a0'-1)/a0 (a0*a)`, which I don't think helps you. In any case, there should be an intelligent transformation that sidesteps the issue of a0 and b0 going to zero. I'll try to spend a little more time on this too.

Comment: Consider posting this question on [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), it probably will attract the attention of the larger crowd there.

Comment: @JoeyDumont Thanks for taking a look.  I thought about re-expressing everything in terms of `a0*a` or `a/a0`, but it wasn't clear immediately how that would help because you still end up dividing by `a0` (I'll give it more of a go today).  The other disadvantage of this is that it requires computing `a0'` which in my case is not too easy (but if need be I can pre-computing it to speed things up).

@AntonMenshov Thanks, I'll try posting it there!

Comment: Could you post the link to your Computational Science question? I'd like to follow through. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the final denominators, `a0(t)` vs. `b0(0)` ? If the correct term is with `b0(t)`, then `a'(t)+b'(t)=0` !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed there was a typo. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Then a(t)+b(t)=Cst and you might consider getting rid of b.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your DEs are so called stiff differential equations ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). This basically means that explicit methods aren't stable for regular step sizes. I suppose you are using the classical Runge-Kutta Method (RK4), which works well in most cases but sadly happens to be an explicit method.

The best way to solve this problem is to simply use an implicit Runge-Kutta method, for example using the Gauss-Legendre method (worked fine for me). If you need help with the implementation, here is a python code I wrote for implicit Runge-Kutta methods:

```
from numpy import double, finfo, array, zeros, dot, size, inf, all, max, min, abs
from numpy import linspace, triu, sqrt, allclose, sign
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

Gauss4 = array([[1/2 - sqrt(3)/6, 1/4            , 1/4 - sqrt(3)/6],
                [1/2 + sqrt(3)/6, 1/4 + sqrt(3)/6, 1/4            ],
                [0              , 1/2            , 1/2            ]])


Gauss6 = array([
        [1/2 - sqrt(15)/10, 5/36              , 2/9 - sqrt(15)/15, 5/36 - sqrt(15)/30],
        [1/2              , 5/36 + sqrt(15)/24, 2/9              , 5/36 - sqrt(15)/24],
        [1/2 + sqrt(15)/10, 5/36 + sqrt(15)/30, 2/9 + sqrt(15)/15, 5/36              ],
        [0                , 5/18              , 4/9              , 5/18              ]])

def nicer_fsolve(F, initial_guess):
    """Wrapper for `scipy.optimize.fsolve`.

    This wrapper is used to solve non-linear equations of multidimensial arrays.
    """
    shape = initial_guess.shape

    initial_guess = initial_guess.reshape((-1,))
    result = fsolve(lambda x: F(x.reshape(shape)).reshape((-1)), initial_guess)

    return result.reshape(shape)

def imp_RKstep(B,f,y0,t0,h):
    """
    Calculates y(t0 + h) using a given an implicit Butcher-tableau B and its corresponding 
    Runge-Kutta method.

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Input:

    B:  Butcher-tableau. For knots c, weights b and the matrix A this should look like

        B = c | A
            ------
            0 | b^T

    f: Right-hand-side of the differential equation y'(t) = f(t,y)

    y0: Starting vector at time t = t0

    t0: Initial time

    h:  Step size

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:

    y: The result y(t0 + h)
    """
    y0 = array(y0)

    c = B[:-1,0]     # Knots
    b = B[-1,1:]     # Weights
    A = B[:-1,1:]    # Matrix A

    s = len(c)       # Number of Knots
    d = len(y0)      # Dimension of y

    def F(x):
        k_x = zeros((s,d))
        for i in range(s):
            k_x[i,:] = f(t0 + h*c[i], y0 + h*dot(A[i,:],x))
        return k_x

    guess = zeros((s,d))
    k = nicer_fsolve(lambda x: F(x) - x,guess) # Solving the non-linear system of equations

    y = y0 + h*dot(b,k)
    return y


def rk(B,f,tspan,y0,N):
    """
    Calculates the solution of an ordinary differential
    equation with right-hand-side f

        y'(t) = f(t,y)
        y(t0) = y0

    using a the Runge-Kutta method encoded in the Butcher-tableau B
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Input:

    B: Butcher-tableau of the two Runge-Kutta method used to calculate the 
       solution. For knots c, weights b and the matrix A this should look like

       B = c | A
           ------
           0 | b^T

       , where Aij = 0 for i <= j (explicit method).


    f: Right-hand-side of the differential equation y'(t) = f(t,y)

    y0: Initial value y(t0) = y0

    tspan: Tuple (t_0,t_end) of start and end times


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Returns: t, y

    t: The times at which y(t) is calculated
    y: The calculated solutions y(t)

    """

    y0 = array(y0,ndmin=1)

    method = imp_RKstep

    # Initialization
    t0,tend=tspan
    t, h = linspace(t0,tend,N+1,retstep=True)
    y = zeros((N+1,) + y0.shape)
    y[0,:] = y0

    # Integrating the solution
    for i in range(N):
        y[i+1,:] = method(B,f,y[i,:],t[i],h)

    return t,y
```

You can call the method for example using

```
t, y = rk(Gauss6,rhs,[0,10],y0,100)
```

, where `y0` are your initial conditions and `rhs` is the right-hand-side of your DE. Let me know if you need help. I am sure there are also implicit methods in standard libraries if you are not using other development environments.

Alternatively, adaptive methods should work as well, although again if you are using explicit methods such as `ode45` they will take a very long time as the step size needs to be decreased.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this implicit method a go.  I was using an adaptive RK method, but it very quickly went to a step size of 0.

Comment: So I tried your code (exactly as is), and it unfortunately doesn't work 100%.  It works for a longer period than the explicit RK method, but eventually the solution to `a(t)` diverges to very large values (~100 or more).  I'll see if I can use your code as a stepping stone.

Comment: @JP-Ellis This is strange, how large are the values of t at which it diverges? I tried it for t = 10000 an it worked (of course for such high values of t you have to increase the amount of steps N). You can also build an adaptive system using the two Butcher-Tableaus I provided (Gauss4 and Gauss6). This worked even better for me.

Comment: I've figured out where it stops working: If the time translations between `a0(t)` and `b0(t)` is too large.  In the example above, I have `(t - 0.6)` and `(t - 0.3)` and that's fine; but if I change it to `t - 6` and `t - 3` it stops working.  A difference greater than about `3` causes the issue for me.  You can download an non-working example at: https://gist.github.com/JP-Ellis/6e5a44212e2c555d6ff136e28c3d8ff8.  I'll try and see if I can fix this somehow.